# Manage back navigation after action_view intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

Activity is started by intent Action_view. When I press back button the app closes. How can I start main activity instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override  onBackpress method in Activity remove super(); 
and do what ever you want on back press

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //put your intent here 
    }
```